# Change class every few seconds from values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to change class on a div every 3 seconds. Classes are in array, previous class should be removed and next one added. "First" should be first, then "second", then "third" and back to loop.

I know how to `addClass('something')` but I am stuck on part where code should put the next available class from array.

```
<div id="main"></div>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

    function changeBackground() {
        var className = $('#main').attr('class');
        if (className == null)
            className = images[0];

        $('#main').removeClass(function () {
            var newClass = // find value in array and take next value, if end of array get first
                $(this).addClass(newClass);
        });
    }

    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skd636fc/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass a function into `removeClass`. You do need to keep track of what class you're on so you can move to the next on the next timer tick. I've explained in the comments:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){   

    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
    // Remember where we are in the array, start just before the first entry
    var classIndex = -1;

    function changeBackground() {

        // Grab the element
        var main = $("#main");

        // If this isn't the first time, remove the previous class
        if (classIndex >= 0) {
            main.removeClass(images[classIndex]);
        }

        // Update the index, wrapping around when we reach the end of the array
        classIndex = (classIndex + 1) % images.length;

        // Add the new class
        main.addClass(images[classIndex]);
    }

    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);

});
```

Notes about the above:

- It's obviously much more compact without explanatory comments
- It won't wipe out other, unrelated classes on `#main` (whereas solutions using `removeClass()` with no arguments will)

Here's a more compact version if you're into that kind of thing. I wouldn't suggest compacting it to quite this degree, though. :-)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
    var classIndex = 0, images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
    $("#main").addClass(images[classIndex]);
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#main")
            .removeClass(images[classIndex])
            .addClass(images[classIndex = (classIndex + 1) % images.length]);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a counter to keep the track of the class index.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4o27tj04/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        i = 0; // Counter to keep track of the class index

    // Cache the element reference
    var $main = $('#main');

    function changeBackground() {
        $main.attr('class', images[i++]); // Set the class attribute value
        i = i % images.length; // If greater than class length, reset back to 0
    }

    // Add first class on page load
    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        i = 0;

    var $main = $('#main');
    function changeBackground() {
        $main.attr('class', images[i++]);
        i = i % images.length;
    }

    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
});
```

```css
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first {
    background-color: #f01 !important;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
}

.third {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

If possible, add the first class to element from HTML

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4o27tj04/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main" class="first"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        i = 0;

    var $main = $('#main');
    setInterval(function () {
        $main.attr('class', images[++i % images.length]);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        i = 0;
    var $main = $('#main');
    setInterval(function () {
        $main.attr('class', images[++i % images.length]);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first {
    background-color: #f01 !important;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
}

.third {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="first"></div>
```

Comment: Tushar, Since it will run infinitely, it is good to cache the selector outside.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
      i = 0;

     function changeBackground() {
         $('#main').attr('class', images[i++]);
         i = i % images.length;
     }

     changeBackground();
     setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first {
    background-color: #f01 !important;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
}

.third {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a `counter` variable. Increment it inside the `setInterval` and use modulo math to create a circular reference to the array's index,

```
var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
var $elem = $('#main'), cnt = 0;

function changeBackground(){
 $elem.removeClass().addClass(images[cnt++ % images.length]);
}

setInterval((changeBackground(), changeBackground), 2000);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/skd636fc/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do,

```
var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

function changeBackground() {
  var className = $('#main').attr('class');
  var newIndex = (images.indexOf(className) + 1) % images.length;
  $("#main").removeClass().addClass(images[newIndex]);
}
setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3616/)