# Change class every few seconds from values in array in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change class on a div every 3 seconds. Classes are in array, previous class should be removed and next one added. "First" should be first, then "second", then "third" and back to loop.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

    function changeBackground() {
        var className = $('#main').attr('class');
        if (className == null)
            className = images[0];

        $('#main').removeClass(function () {
            var newClass = // find value in array and take next value, if end of array get first
                $(this).addClass(newClass);
        });
    }

    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing the same course as the user who asked the first question, as your code is literally *identical*.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var images = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
      i = 0;

     function changeBackground() {
         $('#main').attr('class', images[i++]);
         i = i % images.length;
     }

     changeBackground();
     setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first {
    background-color: #f01 !important;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
}

.third {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859922/change-class-every-few-seconds-from-values-in-array/36860169#36860169)